# Dúvida com sql no laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hoje eu tenho uma consulta que está me retornando dados duplicados, fiz a alteração do sql mais precisava trocar ele.

Como eu posso deixar na mesma estrutura do select(DB::raw?

O código atual esta assim:

```
    $atividades = $this->atividade->select(DB::raw
        ('sum(num_total_pessoas) as total_pessoas,
          sum(convite_prod) as total_convite_prod,
          sum(convite_apaa) as total_convite_apaa,
          sum(educativo_producao) as total_educativo_producao,
          sum(educativo_apaa) as total_educativo_apaa,
          sum(atend_social_producao) as total_atend_social_producao,
          sum(atend_social_apaa) as total_atend_social_apaa,
          MONTH(data) as data2,
          data_fim,plano_id,
          programa_id,
          tipo_publico_id'))->
    where('plano_id',$id)->
    groupBy('tipo_publico_id','data2','programa_id')->get();
```

minha nova consulta esta assim:

```
       echo "<hr/>teste de consulta nova <br/>";
   $results = DB::select(' select 
                            sum(a.num_total_pessoas) as total_pessoas,
                            sum(a.convite_prod) as total_convite_prod,
                            sum(a.convite_apaa) as total_convite_apaa,
                            sum(a.educativo_producao) as total_educativo_producao,
                            sum(a.educativo_apaa) as total_educativo_apaa,
                            sum(a.atend_social_producao) as total_atend_social_producao,
                            sum(a.atend_social_apaa) as total_atend_social_apaa,
                            MONTH(a.data) as data2,
                            a.data_fim,plano_id,
                            a.programa_id,
                            a.tipo_publico_id
                            from atividades a 
                            group by a.tipo_publico_id');
   var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só arrumar o group by da query anterior, não precisa remover o DB::raw.

```
$atividades = $this->atividade->select(DB::raw
    ('sum(num_total_pessoas) as total_pessoas,
      sum(convite_prod) as total_convite_prod,
      sum(convite_apaa) as total_convite_apaa,
      sum(educativo_producao) as total_educativo_producao,
      sum(educativo_apaa) as total_educativo_apaa,
      sum(atend_social_producao) as total_atend_social_producao,
      sum(atend_social_apaa) as total_atend_social_apaa,
      MONTH(data) as data2,
      data_fim,plano_id,
      programa_id,
      tipo_publico_id'))->
where('plano_id',$id)->
groupBy('tipo_publico_id')->get(); // alteração foi feita aqui
```

Comment: agradeço a ajuda, eu trabalho com asp.net mvc, estava sofrendo com este php o dia todo, aprendendo na raça